# GWT chart inside a stackpanel

Tags: java, gwt

I have a class that is using a stackpanel which then gets called inside of my another class then get called inside my entry point class.  My question is how can I get a GChart to display within my Stackpanel (only one of the three panels).

```
    package net.gui.client.content;

import net.gui.client.chart.ChartTuple;

import com.google.gwt.dom.client.Style.Unit;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.HTML;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.ScrollPanel;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.StackLayoutPanel;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget;

/*
 author Kenny Watts
 since July 10, 2012
 This class creates the stacked panels that 
 display the data in the main screen of the gui
 */

public class StackPanel extends StackLayoutPanel {
    static int index = 0;
    public static final String PANEL0NAME = "Critical Data:";
    public static final String PANEL1NAME = "Supporting Data:";
    public static final String PANEL2NAME = "Other Data:";
    ChartTuple chartTest = new ChartTuple();

    public StackPanel(int numTabs) {
        super(Unit.PX);
        // for (int i = 0; i < numTabs; i++) {
        add(stackContent(0), PANEL0NAME, 25);
        add(stackContent(1), PANEL1NAME, 25);
        add(stackContent(2), PANEL2NAME, 25);

        // }
        showWidget(numTabs - 1);
        addStyleName("body");
        setAnimationDuration(500);
    }

    private Widget stackContent(int index) {

//      String content = "This is data set numebr: " + index + ""
//              + PanelUtils.randomText() + PanelUtils.randomText();
        ScrollPanel p = new ScrollPanel(chartTest);
        return (p);
    }
}
```

That is my stackpanel and here is my chart class.

```
    package net.gui.client.chart;

import com.googlecode.gchart.client.GChart;

/**
 * Defines a bar-chart of x*x vs. x, with gridlines.
 */

public class ChartTuple extends GChart {

    public ChartTuple() {
        setChartTitle("<b>x<sup>2</sup> vs x</b>");
        setChartSize(150, 150);
        addCurve();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            getCurve().addPoint(i, i * i);
        getCurve().setLegendLabel("x<sup>2</sup>");
        getCurve().getSymbol().setSymbolType(SymbolType.VBAR_SOUTH);
        getCurve().getSymbol().setBackgroundColor("red");
        getCurve().getSymbol().setBorderColor("black");
        getCurve().getSymbol().setModelWidth(1.0);
        getXAxis().setAxisLabel("<b>x</b>");
        getXAxis().setHasGridlines(true);
        getYAxis().setAxisLabel("<b>x<sup>2</sup></b>");
        getYAxis().setHasGridlines(true);
    }
}
```

And lastly here is my entry point class:

```
package net.gui.client;

import com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.RootLayoutPanel;

/**
 * Main entry point class for the ISCI gui. this just add's the BasePanel to the
 * rootlayoutpanel so it can be put into the HTML file.
 */
public class ISCI implements EntryPoint {

    @Override
    public void onModuleLoad() {
        BasePanel basePanel = new BasePanel();
        RootLayoutPanel.get().add(basePanel);
    }
}
```

When I run it I get the following error: "  [ERROR] [ISCI] - Line 16: No source code is available for type com.googlecode.gchart.client.GChart.SymbolType; did you forget to inherit a required module?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you inherit by GChart gwt module?

```
<inherits name='com.googlecode.gchart.GChart' />
```

Comment: Yes.  I actually just tried that and now I am getting a new error.  "Loading inherited module 'com.googlecode.gchart.client.GChart'
         [ERROR] Unable to find 'com/googlecode/gchart/client/GChart.gwt.xml' on your classpath; could be a typo, or maybe you forgot to include a classpath entry for source?"  I checked the classpath and everything is spelled correct and is in the gchart.jar.

Comment: Actually nevermind I just retyped it into my module and it works now, however it does not display my chart now.

Comment: 1. everytime you create new ScrollPanel(chartTest); charttest is detached from previous scrollpanel and attached to new one. in the end it will be attached to the last one. 2. try setting size on scrollpanel: scroller.setSize("100px", "100px");

Comment: so then my code should look like this:  

ScrollPanel p = new ScrollPanel();
  p.add(chartTest);
  p.setSize("100px", "100px");
  return (p);